# Google Maps API 3 inside ASP.NET Web User Control

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, custom-controls

When my page loads, no map is displayed.  There are no errors in the console either.

If I take both JS script tags (and contents) along with the 2 div containers, and place them just above the form tag in Default.aspx.... it works just fine.

I know the custom control is being loaded, because if i put in a simple textbox it shows up.

---

I've got my **Default.aspx page**

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="DnnTest._Default" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/DnnTestView.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="DnnTestView" %>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div>
                <uc1:DnnTestView runat="server" id="DnnTestView" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

And the **Custom User Control** "DnnTestView.ascx"

```
<%@ Control Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="DnnTestView.ascx.vb" Inherits="DnnTest.DnnTestView" %>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[our key here]&sensor=true">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 var lat = 41.4934579;
    var lng = -90.50442090000001;
    var zoom = 14;

    function init() {
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
            zoom: 16
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
            mapOptions);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
            title: "ARA"
        });

        marker.setMap(map);
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
</script>

<div id="map-contanier" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    <div id="map-canvas"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#map-container does nothing to do with the size of map.

#map-canvas has 0 height. Thus, set style="height:100%" to that tag

Answer (score 0):

For some reason using percent height on #map-canvas didn't work for me. I had to set it to pixels.

```
height:100px;
```